# Stanford NER Training - Assign weight to each word

Tags: nlp, language-model, stanford-nlp

I am using the Stanford NER to recognize each entity in a search text. Once I identify entities, I need to pass that entities to an algorithm which calculates score for each entity type (e.g. country, customer) using weights of each word. Currently my training data has word and answer like below:

```
country_training.tsv
    brazil country
    japan country
    
customer_training.tsv
    hyundai customer
    apple customer
```

How can I associate weight to each above training data like below so when I can get weight of each word too?

```
country_training.tsv
    brazil country 1.5
    japan country 4.0
    
customer_training.tsv
    hyundai customer 4.0
    apple customer 2.3
```

Please advise.

Weights are input to NER to annotate each entity wiith their weights.

Comment: Are weights input or output of Stanford NER?